# SSH : Public key auth only!

Tags: ssh, public-key

Does somebody know. How i can configure sshd to connect ONLY with Public Key Auth?

**currentStatus** : If you have no key. then you can log in with your password.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure the following configuration items are set like this in your `sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

Comment: it's still possible to enter the password.I think it need more configuration

Comment: Have you restarted ssh?

Comment: i did restart the sshd. still .. its possible .
BUT : I changed UsePAM to no . now it works fine :)